# Queue Python background job from Rails server

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, queue, jobs

I have a web frontend based on a Ruby On Rails app that inserts data into a Postgresql database.  When the database gets new data it should be analyzed by using a Numpy/Scipy script. Is there an easy way to queue Python background jobs using Ruby?

One way I guess would be to use [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) (or some other Ruby job queuing system) to process a Ruby background script that again calls the Python script using the command line. Are there any other (better) alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will sharing data with [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) between Python and Ruby work for you ?

Like

```
#ruby
insert into DB my-data
put my-data onto shared-queue
```

then

```
#python 
while True:
   take my-data from shared-queue 
   process my-data
   put did-process-data on shared-queue
```

This would save Ruby calling Python or vice-versa but I'm unsure if you need transactional integrity etc.

Comment: Thanks, looks very good. I also found RabbitMQ by your answer. An alternative to beanstalkd with some more features, but heavier.

Comment: What I liked about ``beanstalkd`` was it was trivial to install, RabbitMQ is industrial strength and heavy weight, that's not to disrespect it. Beanstalkd seems to have good heritage and I'm sure there are similar solutions out there. These sort of things are easier to test as you can create many hundreds of requests and then benchmark how long it takes for 'n' Python clients to process them. etc etc.